# Find, Add, Replace every time - sequentially

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have an input like this, i would like to append a value and it should add value to the next found ID and it should increment sequentially for every value it finds in the file

In short, find FR: (516554) & AT:(929121) and add sequential number to it and replace the value with new generated value FR: (516554001) & AT:(929121001)

my input file 'NKN+S:KSSSS+**FR:516554**+20020716++2'NKN+S:KSSSS+**AT:929121**+19991116++2' 'NKN+S:KSSSS+**FR:516555**+20020716++2'NKN+S:KSSSS+**AT:929122**+19991116++2' 'NKN+S:KSSSS+**FR:516556**+20020716++2'NKN+S:KSSSS+**AT:929123**+19991116++2'

Output file should be something like this 'NKN+S:KSSSS+**FR:516554001**+20020716++2'NKN+S:KSSSS+**AT:929121001**+19991116++2' 'NKN+S:KSSSS+**FR:516555002**+20020716++2'NKN+S:KSSSS+**AT:929122002**+19991116++2' 'NKN+S:KSSSS+**FR:516556003**+20020716++2'NKN+S:KSSSS+**AT:929123003**+19991116++2'

Many thanks in advance

Cheers

Sandy

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, could you please add your sample Input_file and expected sample output into code tags.

Comment: Don't tell us your output should be **something like** anything and then leave it up to us to guess if any particular output we can produce is "something like" what you need or not - just tell us **exactly** what your output must be. [edit] your question to format your input, output, and code using the editors `{}` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have problem to generate the `00x` format number:

```
kent$  seq 10|awk '{printf "%03d\n",$0}'
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
010
```

For your problem, you can set `FS` and `OFS` as `+` and check if the field begins with `FR:/AT:` to decide if the sequence should be added:

```
awk -F'+' -v OFS="+" 
'{s=sprintf("%03d",NR);for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)$x=$x ($x~/^AT:|^FR:/?s:"")}7' input
```

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '$0~/FR|AT/{ c++; gsub(/(FR|AT):[0-9]+/,"\&"sprintf("%03d",c),$0) }1' file
```

The output:

```
'NKN+S:KSSSS+FR:516554001+20020716++2'NKN+S:KSSSS+AT:929121001+19991116++2' 
'NKN+S:KSSSS+FR:516555002+20020716++2'NKN+S:KSSSS+AT:929122002+19991116++2'
'NKN+S:KSSSS+FR:516556003+20020716++2'NKN+S:KSSSS+AT:929123003+19991116++2'
```